# react + typescript export state value

Tags: typescript

i'm new to typescript and I'm unable to understand how can i export state value from one component on same level to another component in same level? Please guide. Here's my demo code from the project i'm working on.

```
const Main = ()=>{
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

}
export default Main
```

I've set the value of User with `setUser()` and don't know how i can export the value for `user` from `Main.tsx` to `CompA.tsx` on same level. Please need some guidance

Comment: You can't share state between 2 sibling components, you have to use redux/context to share state between siblings.

Comment: can you share any relevant material to read about it?